# Checking user existence in vue when editing

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to check the user existence in vue with vuetify inputs when someone tries to edit a User. If the username already exists, then I throw an error, except if this username is the old username, if the user being edited in the moment didn't have his name changed.
But something in the mode It calls my function seems broken but I don't know why, I've put the function in the rules:

```
nameRules: [
            v => !!v || 'Obrigatory field',
            v => (v && (v.length <= 20 && v.length >= 2)) || 'Less than 20 and more than 2 characters',
            v => ( v && (/^[a-z0-9]+$/.test(v))) || 'Only digits and lowercase letters',
            v => ( v && this.checkUserExistence(v)) || 'User already exists'
        ]
```

The function:

```
checkUserExistence(v){
        this.usersdata.some(user => {
          if(user.username != this.oldusername){
            return user.username == v
          }
          else {
            return true
          }
        })
```

It looks like it is ignoring the true/false statements and showing the error anyway!
},

Comment: Throw a `debugger` in the `checkUserExistence` and what does `this.usersdata` look like?

Comment: I already tried. It should be returning correctly but it's not. It is an array of objects.

Comment: can you post this array or give an example of how it looks, otherwise it's difficult to debug

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrongly. The right answer:

```
checkUserExistence(v){
        return this.oldusername !== v && this.usersdata.some(user => user.username === v)
      },
```

And the rule:

```
v => (v && !this.checkUserExistence(v)) || 'Nome de usuário já existe'
```